# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeArray' and 'datetime.date'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a panda column that's in `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>` and also a variable (date_1) that's in `<class 'datetime.date'>`

I like to calculate the month between both as follow but got the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeArray' and 'datetime.date'`

```
df['Duration (months)']= (date_1 - df['Date'])/np.timedelta64(1,'M')
```

How can I calculate the duration in months between the variable of date_1 and df['Date']?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with `to_datetime()`:

```
date_1=pd.to_datetime(date_1)
```

**OR**

try with `pd.Timestamp()`:

```
date_1=pd.Timestamp(date_1)
```

Finally:

```
df['Duration (months)']= (date_1 - df['Date'])/np.timedelta64(1,'M')
```